# 巨大なSubversionリポジトリの一部のみをローカルにチェックアウトしたい

Tags: svn

Subversion（SVN）で管理されているプロジェクト（具体的にはTeX Live）の開発に参加します。私は別のバージョン管理システムGitの扱いにはある程度慣れていますが、SVNは初めて使用します。このプロジェクトのSVNで管理されているソースツリーは巨大で、その全体をローカルにチェックアウトすると20GB以上の容量を必要とします。しかし、私自身が開発上必要とするのはこのうちのごく一部のみで、そのわずかなサブツリーの開発に関わるために、巨大なツリー全体をローカルに保存したくはありません。

そこで、SVNのツリー全体ではなく、自分が開発上必要となるサブツリーのみをローカルに持ってくるようにしたいと思うのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか？ ただし、開発への参加が目的であるため、ある時点でのサブツリーのスナップショットを単にファイルとしてローカルに保存（例えば`rsync`）すればよいのではなく、以下のようなSVN操作をローカルで行えるようにしておく必要があります。

- SVNツリーのうちローカルにある部分について、リポジトリ側で変更があった場合、これをローカルに反映したい
- SVNツリーのうちローカルにある部分について、ローカルで変更を加えた場合、これをリポジトリにコミットしたい
- SVNツリー全体について、ログの閲覧をしたい

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitは分散型のバージョン管理システムなので、Gitを利用するプロジェクトの開発に参加する場合、基本的にはローカルにリポジトリ本体のコピーを作成（クローン）する必要があります。一方、SVNは中央集権型のバージョン管理システムなので、リポジトリ本体は中央のサーバのみに存在するのが大前提です。開発に参加する場合、ローカルに作業用コピーを作成（チェックアウト）しますが、これにより作成されるのはあくまで作業用コピーであってサーバにあるSVNリポジトリ自体の複製ではありません。

上記の前提があるため、SVNの巨大リポジトリでの開発に参加するために、そのソースツリー全体をローカルに保存する必要はありません。ローカルの作業コピーは、開発に必要となる部分だけでも大丈夫です。ツリー全体ではなく、その一部をローカルにコピーする場合には深さ（depth）という概念が重要になります。以下では、巨大なソースツリーの一部をローカルにチェックアウトする具体的な手順を説明します。なお、以降ではリモートのSVNリポジトリ（例えば`svn://tug.org/texlive/`）を`$SVN_REPO`、ローカルの作業コピーを作成するパス位置を`$WORKING_COPY`で参照することにします。

まず、`--depth=empty`を指定して必要なツリーのルートのみ（深さ0）をチェックアウトします。

```
svn checkout --depth=empty $SVN_REPO/trunk $WORKING_COPY
```

これでSVNリポジトリにあるツリーのルート（正確にはtrunk）の作業コピーが位置`$WORKING_COPY`に作成されました。深さ0で作成しているので、この時点では`$WORKING_COPY`の配下には（隠しディレクトリ`.svn`を除き）何もありません。しかし、`$WORKING_COPY`に移動すれば、この時点で`svn log`によってtrunkのログを表示することは可能です。Gitと異なり、作業コピーはローカルにすべての履歴情報を保持しているわけではないので`svn log`の実行にはネットワーク接続が必要です。

続いて、以下のいずれかのコマンドを必要な回数実行して、欲しいサブツリーを構築します。なお`<SOME_PATH>`は`trunk`以下の適当なパスを意味します。

- `svn update --set-depth empty $SVN_REPO/trunk/<SOME_PATH>`: `<SOME_PATH>`を空のディレクトリ（深さ0）として作業コピーに追加
- `svn update --set-depth immediates $SVN_REPO/trunk/<SOME_PATH>`: `<SOME_PATH>`とその直下のファイルを作業コピーに追加
- `svn update --set-depth infinity $SVN_REPO/trunk/<SOME_PATH>`: `<SOME_PATH>`とその配下のすべてのファイルを再帰的に作業コピーに追加

ここで`<SOME_PATH>`は1階層ずつ掘り進めていく必要があります。つまり、`$SVN_REPO/trunk/A`がまだ作業コピーにない状態で`$SVN_REPO/trunk/A/B`に対して`svn update`を実行することはできません。

これらの反復作業により、必要十分なサブツリーを作業コピー（`$WORKING_COPY`）内に作成します。

必要なサブツリーをローカルの作業コピー内に作成し終えると、リポジトリ側の変更を作業コピー内に取り込んだり、逆にローカルで行った変更をリポジトリに反映することが可能になります。

リポジトリ側の変更を作業コピー内に取り込む場合は、`$WORKING_COPY`に移動して`svn update`を実行します。これによりローカル作業コピーのサブツリーの範囲内でリポジトリ側に変更内容があれば、それがローカルに反映されます。SVNリポジトリ自体に新しいコミットがあったとしても、作業コピーのサブツリー範囲に影響がない場合は作業コピーは変更されません。

ローカルの変更をリモートに反映する場合は、作業コピー内のファイルを編集した上で、`svn commit`を実行します。SVNは分散型のバージョン管理システムではないので、Gitのコミットとは異なりコミットの時点でリポジトリ側にその変更が反映されるので少し注意が必要です。

このようにすることで、巨大なSVNリポジトリのすべての内容をローカルに保存することなく、SVNリポジトリを用いた開発に参加することができます。